# Angular Js get Json not working

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple angular app which reads json data , but in response I'm only getting "," not data.Any pointers where I m going wrong ? I have attached index.html and abc.json file that i m keepingat server
PFB the code .

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in students | filter:name">{{student.name +","+student.empNo}</li>
    </ul>
    Name:<input type="text" ng-model="newname">
    EmpNo:<input type="text" ng-model="newemp">
    <input type="button" value="AddMe" ng-click="add()"/>
    <div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var x=angular.module('sampleApp',[])
.factory("simpleFactory",function($http){
    var factory={};
    factory.getStudents=function(){
        return $http.get("abc.json");
    }
        return factory;
    })
    .controller("ctrl1",function($scope,simpleFactory){
        $scope.students=simpleFactory.getStudents();
        $scope.add=function(){
        $scope.students.push(
            {
            name:$scope.newname,empNo:$scope.newemp
            }       
        )
    }
})
```

abc.json

```
[           
  {"name":"jack","empNo":"1"},
  {"name":"Red","empNo":"2"},
  {"name":"Jill","empNo":"3"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getStudents is asynchronous. You should retrieve and assign students through the callback handler.

```
  .factory("simpleFactory",function($http){
            var factory={};
            factory.getStudents = $http.get("abc.json");
            return factory;
         })
        .controller("ctrl1",function($scope,simpleFactory){
            simpleFactory.getStudents().then(function(result) {
                  $scope.students= result.data;
            });
            ...            
        })
```

Comment: ya its working but why result.data not only result ?

Comment: the full response object is passed to the .then handler which has the HTTP status (.status), and HTTP header (.headers), in addition to the payload (.data).

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782567/angular-resource-is-not-working/27782995#27782995" ne pointers on this , why this is not working ?

Answer (score 2):

Nearly right. `getStudents` in fact returns you a 'Promise', not the data itself.  You have to use that Promise to get your data:

```
simpleFactory.getStudents().then(function(data) {
  $scope.students=data
  // $scope.students=data.data      // you may need this given your feedback
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you are wrapping your json in an extra layer called data (i.e. `{data: {"name:...}}`) on the server side