# Angular $resource is not working

Tags: angularjs

The below code when using $http is working,now i m replacing $http with $resource and i have included the dependency and script for resource but i m getting error No Module - ngmodel . Where am i going wrong ?

```
var x= angular.module('sampleApp',['ngResource'])
.factory("simpleFactory",function($resource){
    var factory={};
    factory.getStudents=function(){
        return $resource("abc.json");
    }
    return factory;
})
.controller("ctrl1",function($scope,simpleFactory){
    simpleFactory.getStudents().then(
    function(result){
        $scope.students=result.data;
    })
})
```

Comment: you may need to check the path of json file

Comment: You can try `$http.get("abc.json")`, However you need to go through [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the function call is a resource class object which has the following five methods by default:

```
get()
query()
save()
remove()
delete()
```

Modify your factory to call one these methods:

```
.factory("simpleFactory",function($resource){
     var factory={};
     factory.getStudents=function(){
         return $resource("abc.json").query();
     }
    return factory;
})      .controller("ctrl1",function($scope,simpleFactory){
    $scope.students = simpleFactory.getStudents();
}
```

Comment: ya got that , Actually i was thinking that $resource also returns a promise ... ty :)